# Put text within equation centered

Tags: spacing, equations, align, text, horizontal-spacing

I want to put text between the two equations, but have no idea to make this better, which means that I want there is each space on the both sides of "or".
The codes:

```
\begin{align*} 
  I = (0, 0, x_3) \text{or} I = (0, x_2, 0)   
\end{align*}
```

The image is as below.
[image]

Comment: don't use `align` for one-line equations, use `\[..\]` but you can use `\quad \text{or}\quad` for example to give space.

Comment: Do pay attention to @DavidCarlisle's advice about `align` and `\[...\]`.  Regarding space, remember that spaces typed in the input are ignored in math, but when you specify `\text` any spaces typed within that scope are honored.  So `\text{ or }` is also a possibility here.

Answer (score 4):

You could add spaces in `\text` or add `\quad`s or `\qquad`s on both sides, depending on how much space you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  I = (0, 0, x_3) \text{ or } I = (0, x_2, 0) \\
  I = (0, 0, x_3) \quad\text{or}\quad I = (0, x_2, 0) \\
  I = (0, 0, x_3) \qquad\text{or}\qquad I = (0, x_2, 0)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I recommend you use `\textup` instead of `\text` to guarantee the upright shape,  unless you want the "or" to take on properties from the surrounding text.